# jQuery dialog, static position on current screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dialog that is a search and replace.  Currently I use a method like below to readjust the position of the window.  I need to keep the window static on the screen while (wherever the user has dragged the window to) without moving it around, or resetting it back to the middle of the screen, which is what `jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog("option","position","center");` currently does.

Below is a sample from the [documentation of jQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).  I'm wondering how I should modify the setter value to reposition the window based on the current viewport settings.  So when it auto scrolls on the page it will always remain at X and Y on the current viewport.

```
//getter
var position = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", 'top' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for scroll and resize:

```
$(window)
        .resize(function() {
            $('body').css('height', $(this).height())
            $('#alertsWindow').dialog( "option", "position", ['left','bottom'] );
        })
        .scroll(function(){$(this).resize()});
```

It keeps the dialog in the corner. (You can use any position you want to use)

Right from the [jQuery UI page on dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position):

```
position   String, Array                       Default:'center'
Specifies where the dialog should be displayed. Possible values: 
1) a single string representing position within viewport: 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'. 
2) an array containing an x,y coordinate pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of viewport (e.g. [350,100]) 
3) an array containing x,y position string values (e.g. ['right','top'] for top right corner).
```

Comment: Is it possible to fill `left` and `bottom` with actual X and Y coordinates?

Comment: @Webnet, yes it is. fill it with whatever coordinates you desire :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {$(".selector").dialog("option", "position", ['center','top']);});

$(window).scroll(function() {$(".selector").dialog("option", "position", ['center','top']);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but a much better fix is to set position: fixed on the containing dialog element. No code involved, CSS will take care of everything for you. You will need to reset the position to fixed after a resizing operation by the jQuery resizable plug-in, because the plug-in co-opts the position CSS attribute and sets it to absolute.